# Can I send private messages on askbot?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello, is there also a opportunity to write private messages here to members??
if yes , how? i can`t find .

greets

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12456/can-i-send-private-messages-on-askbot?/) by [hmmm](https://answers.ros.org/users/1556/hmmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2011-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general, there is no private messaging provided. It is possible for moderators to send private messages to users and for users to send private messages to the moderator team using the "give feedback" link at the bottom of the page.

Even without private messaging provided by ROS Answers, you can sometimes find the user's email with enough searching (either their weblinks or previous ros-users posts). Keep in mind the [Support Guidelines](http://ros.org/wiki/Support), namely that questions sent directly to developers will not help the community at large the next time a similar question comes up.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2011-12-26**:
If you use The @user name it will notify them that you have replied to them.